# Email set up in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-email-settings-api

We have domain registered on godaddy and mapped into Google App Engine. Now we want to set up email address with our domain. Can anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's simple, you can use any Email Provider with that.
The Email Provider would need some basic information & would ask you to set at the Same in DNS Settings of your Domain(GoDaddy).

Btw what do you mean by Mapped?
You don't need to do anything to setup email address, atleast on AWS.